# временной отрезок "предыдущий квартал" postgresql

Tags: postgresql

прошу помочь.
нужно указать в запросе ограничение по времени - промежуток "предыдущий квартал" относительно текущей даты, например, если сегодня 10 января 2022 года, предыдущий квартал - с 1 октября 2021 по 31 декабря 2021

where a.date between date (...предыдущий квартал...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут пригодятся функции:

1. `date_trunc` - обрезать дату, в данном случае до начала квартала
2. `-` что отнять один день

```
where a.date between 
   date_trunc('quarter', date_trunc('quarter', now())::date - 1) -- начало предыдущего квартала
   and date_trunc('quarter', now())::date - 1                    -- конец предыдущего квартала
```